# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' при использовании пустого пароля

Tags: php

Имеем стандартную форму подключения:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "my_db");
```

Подключаемся без ошибок.

Делаю 2 файлика

1) db.php

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(
    $config['db']['server'],
    $config['db']['username'],
    $config['db']['password'],
    $config['db']['name']
);
```

2)config.php

```
$config = array(
    'title' => '#',
    'vk_url' => '#',
    'db' => array(
        'server' => '127.0.0.1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'name' => 'my_db'
    )
);
require "db.php";
```

по сути тоже самое только данные берутся из config.php
дамп

```
{ 
["server"]=> string(9) "localhost"
["username"]=> string(4) "root"
["password"]=> string(0) ""
["name"]=> string(6) "my_db" } }
```

т.е казалось бы всё нормально

мой вариант не пускает меня к БД по причине:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   E:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\localhost\mysite\includs\db.php on
>   line 6 Connection error! Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)
>
> Access denied for user ''@'localhost'

тут как я понимаю юзер сетается как пустое значение
почему так
?

Comment: Должно работать. Точно в реальном коде у вас опечаток нет?

Comment: Попробовал зайти с паролем, юзер становится на место
Т.е. проблема в пустом значении в строке password
как решить?

Comment: К mysqli проблема не имеет отношения. Поставь error_reporting(E_ALL) и смотри, где ты теряешь свои параметры

Comment: пустое значение для пароля тут не при чем. у тебя проблема с именем юзера

Comment: Если я в строку password даю значение 123 например то получаю
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
т.е. теперь имя юзера передаётся нормально

Comment: В строке 
 'password' => ' ',
заменил на 
 'password' => "",
и наконец то полключился, 2 день с этим сражался, само решилось
но всё же если кто то скажет почему это так работает буду благодарен

Comment: Это так не работает. Между '' и "" никакой разницы. Вы нас обманываете(скорее всего себя тоже).

Comment: @vp_arth дак мб пробел был между кавычками, как в написано выше или еще что.

Comment: На самом деле есть такой баг. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67026, https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46457